# How to declare additional properties using declaration merging? Without overwriting the module?

Tags: typescript, merge, express-session

Well I am using express-session, with the typing from definity types (`@types/express-session`)

I notice that the types don't have anything for custom data in the session fields. Which is not that useful. I wish to extend this to contain (say) `userId: number`.

The file `@types/express-session` show it can be done using:

```
/**
 * This interface allows you to declare additional properties on your session object using [declaration merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html).
 *
 * @example
 * declare module 'express-session' {
 *     interface SessionData {
 *         views: number;
 *     }
 * }
 *
 */
```

So I created a file named `./src/types/types.ts` And put the following in it:

```
 declare module 'express-session' {
     interface SessionData {
         userId: number;
     }
 }
```

This "works", in that typescript now sees the correct field. On the other hand everything else exposed by `express-sesion` is no longer visible, as typescript no longer considers the other module-definition part. Things like `import {Session} from "express-session";` now give the error:

```
TS2305: Module '"express-session"' has no exported member 'Session'.
```

So how do I extend module definitions?

Answer (score 1):

I was facing something similar and it was actually your question pushed me down the right path.

In the end, I created my own file, `express-session.merge.ts` with the following:

```
declare module 'express-session' {
    interface SessionData {
        someVal: string;
    }
}
export default 'express-session';
```

I then included this at the top of my app.ts, but after the express-session import:

```
import expressSession from 'express-session';
import expressSessionMerge from './express-session.merge';
```

This will then let you use the custom properties in the session:

```
req.session.someVal = 'something';
```

Answer (score 1):

Beside `@David_46592` method, you can also customise your own request type within a customised Context.

For example, you want to add property `UserId`. It can be done with the following.

```js
    import { Connection, EntityManager, IDatabaseDriver } from "@mikro-orm/core";
    import { Request, Response } from "express";
    
    export type MyContext = {
      em: EntityManager<any> & EntityManager<IDatabaseDriver<Connection>>;
      req: Request & { session: { userId?: number } };
      res: Response;
    };
```

Then just import MyContext in your `app.ts` or `index.ts` and use it when you create server as below:

```js
     const apolloServer = new ApolloServer({
        schema: await buildSchema({
          resolvers: [Resolvers...],
          validate: false,
        }),
        context: ({ req, res }): MyContext => ({ em: orm.em, req, res }),
      });
```